# Jekyll: Can an included snippet know where it came from?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

We have a [large document](http://manuals.bvn.com.au/) that's been put online using jekyll and github pages.

When we first made it, we probably went a bit overboard in breaking it up into small bits of content. We used `include` *everywhere*. The intent was that loads of people could contribute to it, but its structure is a bit too complicated.

I'd like to be able to put a link to the file in a github repository after each section of included content. That would allow people to go straight to the part they want to edit.

Is it possible to make something like:

```
<span class="edit-link">{{whereIwasIncludedFrom}}</span>
```

To make this explicit, if a file is in

```
_includes
    A
      my_file.md
```

then the snippet would give

`_includes/A/my_file.md`

I'm currently achieving this by including as a two step process:

```
{% include A/template.markdown box-type="definition" value="A/B/markdown.md" %}
```

calls this:

```
<div markdown="1" class="box-{{ include.box-type }}">
[∞](https://github.com/bvn-architecture/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/_includes/{{ include.value }}){:.edit-link title="Edit this section" target="_blank"}

{% include {{ include.value }} %}

</div>
```

Which works OK, but is a lot of extra typing and complexity if it's possible to get it via a variable.

Comment: What information are you looking for or what info would you like the snippet to have? Are you looking for page name or URL or something identifiable? Do you want the snippet to know its own name or what?

Comment: @ThisClark I added a bit of clarification. I'd like to be able to construct a GitHub url with the information

Answer (score 0):

You know where the snippet is located, why can't you just add the link to the snippet itself instead of the parent?

#### _posts > 2015-11-24-Alphabet.markdown

```
{% include alphabet/letter-a.markdown %}
```

#### _includes > alphabet > letter-a.markdown

```
{% assign child_file = alphabet/alphabet-markdown/a/a-1-key.markdown %}
{% include child_file %}
```

#### _includes > alphabet > alphabet-markdown > a > a-1-key.markdown

```
<span class="transform-to-uppercase">Cover sheet</span>
[Link to a file](https://github.com/bvn-architecture/styleguide/gh-pages/{{ child_file | relative_url }})
```